# Unable to hide the keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, hide

I am trying to hide the keyboard in an iOS app. I've spent several hours looking for it, and I've tried pretty much everything, so I'm quite desperate.

My code follows as next:

RNViewController.h

```
@interface RNViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
     UITextField *textField;
...
}
```

RNController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone; 
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Entering in textFieldShouldReturn ");
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"Entering in textViewShouldReturn ");
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@"Entering in textFieldDoneEditing ");
        [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)textViewDoneEditing:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"Entering in textViewDoneEditing ");
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}


- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
    return NO;
}
```

**EDIT**: The textField is created dinamically like this:

```
- (void) showPreguntaTexto: (Pregunta *) pregunta {
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(baseView.bounds)*0.1, offset + CGRectGetWidth(baseView.bounds)*0.05, CGRectGetWidth(baseView.bounds) - CGRectGetWidth(baseView.bounds) * 0.2 , CGRectGetWidth(baseView.bounds)*0.5)];

    textField.delegate = self;

    [vistaAnterior addSubview:textField];
}
```

My views are the baseView (with elements that do not change) and vistaAnterior, that has the content (and the textField) and changes.

Trying this, it shows that entered to textFieldShouldReturn, but the keyboard does not dissapear.

Why is this happening?? Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resign the sender of the textfield instead of your instance. `UITextField *textField` is not an IBOutlet  (storyboard) or created in code so `textField` is nil (unless you created it somewhere else and didn't show the code).

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"Entering in textViewShouldReturn ");
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you set text fields delegate in your RNViewController from stroyboard. This might be a reason for keyboard not hiding.